# IntelliJ IDEA: regex for removing Oracle to_timestamp syntax

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I'm trying to come up with a search/replace expression that will convert from Oracle style inserts with timestamp fields to insert statements for another database.

Basically, I want to convert strings like:

```
to_timestamp('13-SEP-09 12.00.00.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
```

to just:

```
'13-SEP-09 12.00.00.000000000 PM'
```

I've tried several expressions in the IDEA's search/replace box, but I still can't quite get it. This one:

```
to_timestamp(.[^,]*,.[^)]*)
```

replaced with $1 ends up matching the string I want except the close parenthesis, but then only deletes the first part. I end up with:

```
('13-SEP-09 12.00.00.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
```

I really don't understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
to_timestamp\(('[^']*')[^)]*\)
```

Breaking it down:

`to_timestamp` is obvious

`\(` matches the opening paren

`(` starts capturing

`'[^']'` matches the first quoted string

`)` stops capturing

`[^)]*\)` matches the remaining text

If that's the whole string you're matching, and not just part of a larger text, you can use `.*` instead of `[^)]*\)` for the last part; you don't really care what comes after the closing `'`.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly, and I never would have come up with it on my own. I thought I understood regex fairly well, but I still don't get why we need an escaped parenthesis to match and an unescaped parenthesis to start capturing. If anyone can point me towards a good regex resource, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is a good place to start. Then there are the books: http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0596520689/jgsbookselection and http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0596528124/masteringregu-20